# gem install not working with homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, bundle, homebrew

Ok so i just recently installed homebrew and everything is great but i am running into a problem with installing nokogiri here is my problem

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.1.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.1) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.1) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.2) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.1) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.1) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.1) 
Using arel (3.0.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.2.1) 
Using activeresource (3.2.1) 
Using annotate (2.4.1.beta1) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bundler (1.0.22) 
Installing nokogiri (1.5.0) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/matt_elhotiby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
-----
libiconv is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
```

so I use this command to install it

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.7.8/lib --with-xslt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.26 --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.5.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for nokogiri-1.5.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for nokogiri-1.5.0...
```

Then I run a sanity check and get this

```
gem list nokogiri*** LOCAL GEMS ***
nokogiri (1.5.0)
```

but for some reason the bundle install never works ....,y environment is the following

MAC OSX Lion 
RVM ruby-1.9.2-p290

anything else that i can provide for anyone to help you help me would be great...

and

Answer (score 3):

solved by

```
brew install libiconv
[master (Time to Commit)]$ brew link libiconv
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14... 16 symlinks created
```

Comment: Homebrew removed the `libiconv` formula
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/10464